# AES sending 32 bytes from Java application, only reading 29 bytes from C# application

Tags: c#, java, sockets, encryption-asymmetric

A college's mailroom is in dire need of new software to help with their operations. The current program was written back in the early '90s in what they believe is python. Two others and myself, are modernizing it. I am in charge of the networking and the server. The school requires that we encrypt any sensitive student data being sent across the network. Since we are using two different languages (Java and C#), I had to do a little digging to find the commonalities in encryptions. AES128/CBC/ISO10126 is the common one. The problem I am having, is that if I send to the client, the server key and IV so that the client can encrypt and return the session key and IV, when the server reads it I am missing 3 bytes of data and I cant get it to decrypt at all. Here is how I am reading on the server side after something is sent back

```
        ICryptoTransform decrypter = myProvider.CreateDecryptor(myProvider.Key, myProvider.IV);
        byte[] sKey = new byte[myClient.ReceiveBufferSize];
        Console.WriteLine(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(sKey));
        Console.WriteLine("Key Length: " + sKey.Length);
        byte[] sessionKey = new byte[sKey.Length];
        sessionKey = decrypter.TransformFinalBlock(sessionKey, 0, sessionKey.Length);
```

Any ideas what might be causing me to somehow drop 3 bytes of data? Normally I wouldn't be upset, but the three bytes are important to a secure connection.

Comment: You might want to consider PKCS5 padding instead of ISO10126. I hadn't heard of ISO10126 before and I'm not even aware of a Java implementation of it. I'm not sure if that is causing your problem though. Without seeing the Java code diagnosing this would be challenging.

Comment: Are you saying that the cypher text has 3 bytes missing, or the decrypted cypher text is missing 3 bytes?  Also, why roll your own encryption when you can use SSL instead?

Comment: C# doesn't support PKCS5. it uses PKCS7. and I would use SSL but java throws an error about a bad server certificate(self issued, self signed) and then C# throws an error about a SSPI call not being handled. hence why I am rolling my own encryption.

Comment: and yes I am saying that the cipher text, after being read by the C# application, is missing 3 bytes. but when the java application sends it, it sends to the console that 32 bytes are being sent

Comment: You can easily fix the SSL certificate error by adding the trusted certificate to `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts` using `keytool` or Portecle - http://portecle.sourceforge.net/ - or even specifying a different truststore for your connection.

Comment: I tried that. still didn't wouldn't let me use SSL